# Can Monero transactions contain scripts?

Tags: transaction-data

Does Monero contain a [scripting system for transactions](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script) like Bitcoin does?
If so, what OPs does it have and where is it defined? Is it the same script as in Bitcoin or different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no scripting language in Monero at the moment (the Cryptonote paper describes a simple one, though, if memory serves).

Comment: Correct. Section 6.3 "Transaction scripts" on page 14 of the [CryptoNote whitepaper](https://cryptonote.org/whitepaper.pdf) mentions "CryptoNote has a very minimalistic scripting subsystem."